# Using mislav_will_paginate in embeddable javascript view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Trying to create a view that can serve up a set of paginated results when embedded (through js) in another document.  This is in lieu of using an iframe.  The embed code in the parent document looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://MYWEBSITE/search?query=MYPARAMETERS&embed=true&per_page=20"/>
```

The view (embed.html.erb) that responds to this action looks like this:

```
(function(){

document.write('<div id="df_search_results">')

<% @results.each do |result| %>
    document.write('<a href="<%= result.url %>" rel="lightbox[aj]" title="<%= result.title %>"><img src="<%= result.other_url %>" width="100" height="100" /></a>')
<% end %>

<% if @hits > @results.size %>
    document.write(<%= will_paginate @results %>)
<% end %>

document.write('</div>')

})()
```

This works as expected when the will_paginate tag is excluded.  It fails to render entirely, and does not put any errors in the log, when the will_paginate tag is included.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
document.write(<%= will_paginate @results %>)
```

The output of `will_paginate` method will be inserted in your script but not properly quoted as string passed to the `write()` method. You need to escape it.

In Rails, you can use the [`escape_javascript` method](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript):

```
document.write('<%= j will_paginate(@results) %>')
```

(Notice the single quotes.)

If you don't use Rails, you can [copy its source here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/289540e4ffc1a5619979708e5287a9b71f9ab4e2/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb#L28-37).

Comment: Perfect - I have never needed to escape js before.